# Spring MVC PathVariable for products and categories implementation

Tags: spring-mvc, path-variables

Guys ! 
I develop eCommerce platform but i don't know how to implement the scenario below.
I want to have friendly URLs (for SEO stuff..). 
I have the correct slug in the database for categories and products for example:

www.domain.com/category-tools/

wwww.domain.com/category-laptops/ - which are categories

but i and products which are:

www.domain.com/iphone6s-32gb

www.domain.com/macbook-pro-ssd

How to implement this logic in to the handler below ? How to know when it is product or category ? Do i need to make two separate queries (one for products and one for categories) to the database ?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{categoryOrProduct}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getCategory(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("category", .......);

        if( is category ) {
         return "categoryTemplate"
        }

        return "productTemplate;
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use /products/{id} for products, and /categories/{id} for categories?

Comment: As i said, for SEO optimization. ( products/{id} ) is not valuable enough   for google :)